# How can I record a video of the shader screen with high bitrate from ShaderToy?

Tags: export, video-capture, fragment-shader, bitrate, shadertoy

I've wrote a noisy shader in ShaderToy that I want to record a video from. ShaderToy provides this option but it captures the screen with very low bitrate. Is there any opportunity to get the video in high bitrate (or frame by frame)?

Answer (score 1):

You can render a Shadertoy animation at whatever scale and FPS you like using Natron. It's done by adding a Shadertoy filter, copying in the script, adding a Writer, then exporting as an image sequence. That can be used in Blender or Davinci directly.

Tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GumRHVfLb_g

Another way is to use a ShaderToy plugin in Blender directly. It gives you more power, as shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rh6CNLMSORo